# Kibana giving unauthenticated first time but allowing to login second time in same session

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

<sup>Kibana giving unauthenticated first time but allowing to login second time in same session.</sup>

I have enabled Kibana login from wso2 API manager.

below I have provided Elastic configuration file.
I am following instruction to configure wso2 and kibana- Log in to Elastic Stack with WSO2 Identity Server with OAuth2/OIDC | by Shan Chathusanda Jayathilaka | Medium

But when i login on Kibana first time i am getting unauthenticate error, when i try to login second time in same session, that is sucessfull login.

Not sure what is happening first time.

I have provided logs below, Please help.

Elastic version - 8.6.1

```
xpack.security.authc.realms.oidc.oidc1:
order: 2
rp.client_id: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
rp.response_type: code
rp.redirect_uri: "http://abc:5601/api/security/oidc/callback"
#op.issuer: "https://abc:9443/oauth2/token"
op.issuer: "https://abc/oauth2/token"
op.authorization_endpoint: "https://abc:9443/oauth2/authorize"
op.token_endpoint: "https://abcl:9443/oauth2/token"
op.jwkset_path: "https://abc:9443/oauth2/jwks"
op.endsession_endpoint: "https://abc:9443/oidc/logout"

op.userinfo_endpoint: "https://abc:9443/oauth2/userinfo"
rp.post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://abc:5601/security/logged_out"
claims.principal: sub
claims.groups: groups
ssl.verification_mode: none

claims.name: name
claims.mail: email
```